# PayPal sale within Firefox web extension

Tags: paypal, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to add a button in my Firefox web extension to let users make a payment with PayPal directly within the extension, problem is that if I try to use the [Client-side REST integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/), Firefox complains

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“script-src”).

even if I add `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/ https://www.paypal.com/; object-src 'self'"` to the manifest (and moving the inline script to a separate js file).

So I tried [Server-side REST integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/server-side-REST-integration/), looking at the API I have to create a payment specifying a redirect url where users will be redirected when they give the authorization, but if I try to set an extension page as the redirect I get `unsafe:moz-extension://extension_id/extension_page.html?token=XX-1XX23456XX789012X` and after the the authorization (I tried with the sandbox profile) it doesn't open the page. Is there a way to make the extension "catch" the redirect page as it does using the [`identity.launchWebAuthFlow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow), or any other way to do what I'm asking for? Thanks.